# Spreadsheet and time driven trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula

In a spreadsheet cell I have the following formula:

`=importhtml("http://www.eco.hu/currency/table.htm"& year(now()) & month(now()) & day(now()) & hour(now()) & minute(now());"table";1)`

which refresh some other cells values too.

I will save every day some values from different cells.
I have the following function:

```
function Historia() {
 Utilities.sleep(15000);
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(XXX);
 var rows = ss.getDataRange();
 var values = rows.getValues();

 for (var i=0;i<values.length; i++) { 
      var j = values[i].indexOf("Portf" );
      if (j > -1) { var aktPort = values[i][j+1]; }
  }
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(Hist);
  ss.getRange(4,2).setValue(aktPort) ;

  }
```

When I run Historia by hand it works every time perfect, brings the right result. When I make a Time-driven day timer with this function, it brings almost always a #N/A result in my spreadsheet.

What do I do wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you think about the possibility that "Portf" is never found.

Here's a re-work of your code:

```
function Historia() {
 Utilities.sleep(15000);
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(XXX);
 var rows = ss.getDataRange();
 var values = rows.getValues();
 var aktPort = "";

 for (var i=0;i<values.length; i++) { 
   var j = values[i].indexOf("Portf" );
   if (j > -1) { 
     aktPort = values[i][j+1]; 
     var ss= SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(Hist);
     ss.getRange(4,2).setValue(aktPort);  // since there's only one storage location
     break;                               // no need to look further
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have absolut right! I wasn't able to see my basic error! Thank you very very much!